# Markov processes driven by the noise

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\xi_n\in \Xi$ be a sequence of iid random variables with $n \in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$, which we call a noise process. Construct a process 
$$
Z_{n+1} = f(Z_n,\xi_n)\quad(\star)
$$
with $Z_0\in E$ and $f:E\times\Xi\to E$ is a measurable function of two variables. Clearly, $Z$ is a Markov process.

On the other hand, consider a Markov process $X$ on $E$ given by its transition kernel $P(x,A)$. Is it always possible to find a noise process (on some set $\Xi$) and a measurable function $f:E\times \Xi\to E$ such that given any initial condition (maybe random) $X_0\in E$
$$
\operatorname{Law}(X_1) = \operatorname{Law}(f(X_0,\xi_0))
$$

Briefly speaking, if any Markov process can be presented in the form $(\star)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is 
the representation of a discrete time Markov process
as a **randomized dynamical system** as found in 
Proposition 8.6 (page 145) from *Foundations of Modern Probability (2nd edition)* 
by Olav Kallenberg:

> Let $X$ be a process on $\mathbb{Z}_+$ with values in a Borel space $S$.
>    Then $X$ is Markov iff there
>   exist some measurable functions $f_1,f_2,\dots:S\times[0,1]\to S$
>   and iid $U(0,1)$ random variables $\xi_n$ independent of $X_0$ such that 
>   $X_n=f_n(X_{n-1},\xi_n)$ almost surely for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>   Here we may choose $f_1=f_2=\cdots =f$ iff $X$ is time homogeneous.

Comment: +1! Nice answer, Byron! Hope you are doing well! You might have noticed I have asked a related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144062/is-a-markov-process-a-random-dynamic-system?lq=1