# Generating Markov Chains recursively

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

$X_0:\Omega\rightarrow I$ is a random variable where $I$ is countable. Also $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. $\text{Unif}[0,1]$ random variables.

Define a sequence $(X_n)$ inductively as $X_{n+1}=G(X_n,Y_{n+1})$, where $G:I\times[0,1] \rightarrow I$. Show that $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain and determine the transition matrix in terms of G?

Comment: The problem here may be of some use: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66047/markov-processes-driven-by-the-noise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_{n+1}=G(X_n,Y_{n+1})$ where $Y_{n+1}$ is independent with $X_i$ for all $i$, of course we have
$$\begin{align}P(X_{n+1}|X_n,...,X_0)&=P(G(X_n,Y_{n+1})|X_n,...,X_0)\\&=P(G(X_n,Y_{n+1})|X_n)\\&=P(X_{n+1}|X_n)\end{align}$$
which indicates $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain.

Comment: "As for transition matrix Pt, it is non-homogeneous and relevant to G. The matrix representation of G, if exists, is the transition matrix." The first sentence is false (the Markov chain **is** homogenous), the second one is incomprehensible (what is the "matrix representation" of a function defined on $I\times[0,1]$?).

Answer (score 0):

The question is a particular case of a more general theorem:

> Let $S$ be a numerable set and let $X_0:\Omega \to S$ be a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $\{Y_n\}$, $Y_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^N$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ that are also independent of $X_0$, and let $f:S\times \mathbb{R}^N\to S$ be a Borel function. Then the sequence $\{X_n\}$, $X_n:\Omega \to S$ defined by
>   $$
> X_{n+1}(x) := f(X_n(x), Y_n(x)), \quad \forall\, n \geq 0
> $$
>   is a homogeneous Markov chain with state space $S$ and transition matrix
>   $$
> \mathbf{P}_{ij} = P\left(f(i,Y_k)=j\right) \qquad \forall\, i,j\in S
> $$

Proof. It follows, from the definition, that for any integer $k$, the random variable $X_k$ is a function of $X_0$ and $Y_1,\dots, Y_{k-1}$. Consequently, for any integer $n$, the random variable $Y_n$, which is by definition independent of $(X_0,Y_1, \dots, Y_{n-1})$, is also independent of $(X_0, \dots, X_n)$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
& \ P\left(X_{n+1} = j \big\lvert X_0=i_0, \dots, X_n=i \right) \\
&= P\left(f(i,Y_n)=j \big\lvert X_0=i_0, \dots, X_n=i\right) \\
&= P(f(i,Y_n)=j) \\
&= P\left(f(i,Y_n)=j \big\lvert X_n=i\right)
\end{align*} 
the second equality holds since the random variable $(X_0, \dots, X_n)$ is independent of $Y_n$, hence of $f(i,Y_n)$. This shows that $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain and the transition matrix is $$\mathbf{P}=(\mathbf{P})_{ij} = P(f(i,Y_n)=j)$$ but this last expression is independent of $n$ since the random variables are i.i.d.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$