# Markovian systems: Why must controls be independent of state?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am currently working my way through *Probabilistic Robotics* by Thrun, Burgard, and Fox. On p. 91, I encountered the following statement:

> The Markovian assumption implies  independence between $x_{t-1}$ and $u_t$, and thus $p(x_{t-1}|u_t) = p(x_{t-1})$.

$$x_{t-1} \ldots \text{system state at time } t-1 \\ 
u_t \ldots \text{control input immediately before time } t \\
p(y) \ldots \text{probability of } y $$

I thought hard, but I could not come up with a way to prove the independence between $x_{t-1}$ and $u_t$. Why, for example, is a system with a simple proportional controller $u_t = -x_{t-1}$ not Markovian?

Comment: have you read markov process

Comment: There must be some other assumptions.  In general, the optimal control law will depend on state, adn the states will be dependent one time step to the next.  In general there is dependence between $u_t$ and $x_{t-1}$.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Markov processes can't have any memory. So there can be no dependence between the current state and previous states. My understanding then was $p(x_t|x_0, x_1, ..., x_{t-1}) = p(x_{t})$. That is, by definition, a process is a Markov process whenever it's the result of a chain of independent events.

Comment: I would say that it is an assumption made in order to guarantee the Markov property. See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66047/markov-processes-driven-by-the-noise/66053#66053

Comment: @ColmBhandal: That is not correct: By definition, a Markov process is a process that satisfies the Markovian property, that is $p(x_t|x_{1:t-1}) = p(x_t|x_{t-1})$. This property means that when determining the current state, there is no advantage in knowing more states than the previous state.

Comment: @Lexxer- yes well spotted. That is indeed the correct definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further research and found out the following:

The statement $p(x_{t-1}|u_t) = p(x_{t-1})$ has nothing to do with the Markov assumption. It rather states that control is randomly chosen and not a function of the state.

The assumption of random controls is essential for the Bayes filter: Without this assumption, the Bayes filter algorithm does not hold (cf. p. 32).

Since the quote provided in the original post stems from the mathematical derivation of the histogram filter, which is just an implementation of the Bayes filter, it simply restates the random controls assumption of the Bayes filter.

Comment: The control is randomly chosen  or   the variable $u_t$ will always correspond to the change of state in the time interval. $(t−1;t]$ are different statements. The second requires a markovian assumption. I believe the version of the book we are using is different could you quote the phrase in the Bayes filter that  states that control is randomly chosen and is not a function of the state? Thanks

Comment: @ConradoCosta: Thank you for mentioning the different versions of the book. I just discovered that I have the second, slightly flawed printing. However, there should be no flaws in section *2.4.3 Mathematical Derivation of the Bayes Filter*, where it says (p. 31, just above formula 2.35): *Our derivation requires that the state $x_t$ is complete [...] and it requires that controls are chosen at random.*

Answer (score 0):

I perused the book you mention and found no definition of what is the Markov assumption (the author does have a word on the markov assumption but its  more a critique on the hypothesis then a definition I believe the definition is somewhere else in the lines of conditional independence).

Usually markov assumption is translated as $P(x_{t+1} \mid x_0,\ldots, x_{t}) =p(x_{t+1}\mid x_{t}) $ (this means that the future depends only on the present and nothing more). But in your case  you are dealing with control data $u_t$ and state variable $x_t$ you have the following object:

$$p(x_t \mid x_{t-1},u_t) $$

The probability $p(x_t \mid x_{t−1} , u_t )$ is the state transition probability. It specifies how environmental state evolves over time as a function of robot controls $u_t$ .

Conditional independence then reads as

$$p(x_t \mid x_{0:t−1} , z_{1:t−1} , u_{1:t} )=p(x_t \mid x_{t−1} , u_t ) $$

this means that future and past are independent given the present.
the author says that the variable $u_t$ will always correspond to the change of state in the time interval $(t − 1; t]$

therefore since $x_{t-1}$ is the state at time $t-1$ the variable $u_t$ depends on the future of $x_{t-1}$. We may say that $p(u_t \mid x_{t-1}) = p(u_t)$

this gives $$p(u_t \mid x_{t-1}) = \frac{p(u_t, x_{t-1})}{p(x_{t-1})}= p(u_t) \Rightarrow \frac{p(u_t, x_{t-1})}{p(u_t)}= p(x_{t-1}) = p(x_{t-1} \mid u_{t})$$

this is legitimate once $p(x_{t-1})>0$ and $p(u_t)>0$.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate response! However, I do not agree with your assumption $p(u_t|x_{t-1}) = p(u_t)$, as conditioning random variables does not have to be done in chronological order. For example, if we have a controller $u_t = -x_{t-1}$, $u_t$ does carry information about $x_{t-1}$.

Comment: You are right, conditioning does not have to be done in chronological order,  your example  clearly violates the sentence  the variable $u_t$ will always correspond to the change of state in the time interval. $(t−1;t]$. Any way, I am glad you found an answer.